# What does "god Audate" mean?

Tags: literature, literary-english

In Self-Reliance by Emerson, the online texts I have found say:

> He will then see prayer in all action. The prayer of the farmer
> kneeling in his  field to weed it, the prayer of the rower kneeling
> with the stroke of his oar,  are true prayers heard throughout nature,
> though for cheap ends. Caratach, in  Fletcher's Bonduca, when
> admonished to inquire the mind of the god Audate, replies, --
>
> "His hidden meaning lies in our endeavours; Our valors are our best
> gods."

Is Audate the name of a mythical god, a fictional god in Fletcher's Bonduca, or some kind of label for the Christian god , like "the holy ghost", or something else?

Comment: Sounds to me like a misfit for _Gaudete_, meaning 'Rejoice! [pl]. The third Sunday of Advent is called "Gaudete Sunday" in the Catholic church calendar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [Andraste, also known as Andrasta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andraste#:%7E:text=Andraste%2C%20also%20known%20as%20Andrasta,of%20Britain%20in%20AD%2060.), was, according to the Roman historian Dio Cassius, an Icenic war goddess invoked by Boudica in her fight against the Roman occupation of Britain in AD 60.

Audate is a misprint in the first folio of "Bonduca" by Fletcher, corrected in the second to Andate. https://www.gutenberg.org/files/45781/45781-h/45781-h.htm#Page_112

Andraste = Andrasta = Andate

Answer (score 4):

From Google search:

[UChicgago journals](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/full/10.1086/691606)

"In John Fletcher’s dramatization of ancient Britain’s martial struggle against Roman conquest, Caratach, the British general, invokes **Andate** before a decisive battle."

I think that "Audate" may be a misspelling.
I guess the British gods of the time are prechristian, and there may have been a few.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions [Andraste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andraste), so it's probably another version/spelling of that.

Comment: Could also be a misspelling of "aud**e**te," Latin for "Dare!"

Comment: My first thought was something like "god as heard", but Wiktionary only show "audate" for Esperanto.

Comment: Andate, Bonduca, and Caratach all seem to be deliberate alterations of Andraste, Boudica, and Caratacus.